# Me toma día como mes y mes como día

Tags: date, vba

estoy grabando una macro y estoy tratando de seleccionar una columna con fechas de 1/10/2020 (1 de octubre del 2020) y pegarla en otra hoja, hasta ahí todo parece bien, pero cuando la corro, me toma el día como mes y mes como día cuando la pego en la otra hoja, me aparece 10/01/2020 (10 de enero del 2020) ademas también uso la opción "customer sort" para acomodar y filtrar información y es la misma situación a la hora de correr la macro, ya he intentado de todo si alguien sabe cómo solucionar este problema se lo agradecería muchísimo ya que es para mi trabajo.

Comment: ¿Has revisado el formato de celdas tanto de origen como de destino?

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(3, 3)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").PasteSpecial
```

En el que primero pegas el formato que utiliza la columna y después los valores.

Por favor cambia los rangos y nombres de hojas como requieras.